# why would this where clause using IN as part of subquery return different # of rows when done explicitly?

Tags: mysql

im trying to understand this issue, i have this query

```
SELECT 
  cpt_codes.code,
  ii.insurance_group_name,
  ii.insurance_group_id,
   dcc_total_view.allowedAmount AS `Running Allowed Total`,
  rc_total_view.runningCollectedReceivedByProvider AS `Running Collected Received By Provider`
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
    ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
    ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN rc_total_view
    ON ds.payment_information_id = rc_total_view.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc_total_view
    ON ds.id = dcc_total_view.dos_id
WHERE (cpt_codes.code, ii.insurance_group_name) IN (SELECT 
    cpt_codes.code,
    ii.insurance_group_name  
  FROM ds
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
      ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
      ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
      ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
      ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
      ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
      ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  WHERE cs.status = 'Pending'
  AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
  AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
  OR dcc.rev_code = '0360'))
AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
OR dcc.rev_code = '0360')
AND  dcc_total_view.allowedAmount > 0
```

the subquery in the WHERE clause i thought would run the inner select and then return a list of codes and insurance group name that meet the filtering criteria and then return that to outer query to run against where it would look for returned CODE and any matching insurance group name found.

I ran the subquery by itself to see how many codes and group names it returned

```
SELECT 
    cpt_codes.code,
    ii.insurance_group_name  
  FROM ds
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
      ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
      ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
      ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
      ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
      ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
      ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  WHERE cs.status = 'Pending'
  AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
  AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
  OR dcc.rev_code = '0360')
```

, i then took the list of codes and group names, broke it down to the unique/distinct ones
there were 64 unique codes returned and 320 unique group names. i then replaced the inner query for the where clause with 2 IN statements like this (i pared down the list of codes and group names for example)

```
SELECT 
  cpt_codes.code,
  ii.insurance_group_name,
  ii.insurance_group_id,
   dcc_total_view.allowedAmount AS `Running Allowed Total`,
  rc_total_view.runningCollectedReceivedByProvider AS `Running Collected Received By Provider`
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
    ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
    ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN rc_total_view
    ON ds.payment_information_id = rc_total_view.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc_total_view
    ON ds.id = dcc_total_view.dos_id
WHERE code IN ('43245','22245','22246','22247','20111','20112','20113','34567','345678','345679','357994','546741','123456','658963')
AND insurance_group_name IN (' COX',' CVS ',' FFN LLC',' NE Gas',' Vanguard','ADP','ADP Total Source Inc','ADP Totalsource Group Inc','ADP Totalsource Inc','AHTNA','AHTNA SCA ','APOLLO GROUP INC','AXIOMATICS INC')
AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
OR dcc.rev_code = '0360')
AND  dcc_total_view.allowedAmount > 0
```

this returns nearly 2x many rows as the one with the subquery . so why is that the case ? i thought these would be equivalent but obviously this is not the case. Any ideas of why ? let me know want to make sure im returning all the data needed for this and looks like running via the subquery is missing stuff.  Thanks for any help

Comment: Mysql valid dates are in the form yyyy-mm-dd you appear to be using strings

Comment: not sure i understand? the only date field here is date_of_service and its in that format? also not sure why that would affect my rows returned for the IN part ?

Comment: ' date field here is date_of_service and its in that format?' - is not clear if it's a date datatype  it's stored in the form yyyy-mm-dd not yyyy/mm/dd which makes me suspect it's a string datatype.

Comment: yes its date datatype

Comment: I feel like we've been here before

Comment: this is just more of a question about how the IN command is working is all i listed the queries , so was just wondering if someone maybe had a better understanding of how the IN command was working with the difference. I got it to work by breaking up into seperate includes built with their own subquery, but you keep voting me down till i cant post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase it might help someone else, this is how i got it to return results i needed, im sure for the experts they could do this in 4 lines of code :) but it works and it returns quickly :) Hope it helps someone else

```
SELECT 
  cpt_codes.code,
  ii.insurance_group_name,
  ii.insurance_group_id,
   dcc_total_view.allowedAmount AS `Running Allowed Total`,
  rc_total_view.runningCollectedReceivedByProvider AS `Running Collected Received By Provider`
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
    ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
    ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN rc_total_view
    ON ds.payment_information_id = rc_total_view.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc_total_view
    ON ds.id = dcc_total_view.dos_id
WHERE code IN (SELECT DISTINCT
    cpt_codes.code,
    ii.insurance_group_name  
  FROM ds
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
      ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
      ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
      ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
      ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
      ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
      ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  WHERE cs.status = 'Pending'
  AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
  AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
  OR dcc.rev_code = '0360'))
AND (insurance_group_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT
       ii.insurance_group_name  
  FROM ds
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
      ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
      ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
      ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
      ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
      ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
      ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  WHERE cs.status = 'Pending'
  AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
  AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
  OR dcc.rev_code = '0360'))
OR insurance_group_id  IN (SELECT DISTINCT
       ii.insurance_group_id 
  FROM ds
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
      ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
      ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
      ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
      ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
      ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
      ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  WHERE cs.status = 'Pending'
  AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
  AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
  OR dcc.rev_code = '0360')))
AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
OR dcc.rev_code = '0360')
AND  dcc_total_view.allowedAmount > 0
GROUP BY code,insurance_group_name
```